# Installing graph-tool with local BOOST

Tags: c++, boost, graph-tool

In order to install graph-tool, I must install dependencies with autoconf.

Some of these dependencies use boost, and I link my local boost install to these dependencies with:

```
export BOOST_ROOT=/my/path/boost
./configure
```

And everything proceeds smoothly.  Then, when I shift to graph tool, I get a prompt to add BOOST_ROOT for an "unstaged boost". I don't know what that means, so I try:

```
export BOOST_ROOT=/my/path/boost
./configure
```

And this fails. I then inspect graph-tool's configure script, and it seems like, during the test for boost, it checks the following path:

```
if test -n "$BOOST_ROOT" ; then
    for libsubdir in $libsubdirs ; do
        if ls "$BOOST_ROOT/stage/$libsubdir/libboost_"* >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then break; fi
    done
```

And I review both my boost install and my boost source code checkout, and I see no paths from the boost root directory with "stage" in them.

This seems strange, given that the dependencies were able to include the local boost install using the autoconfigurer. Are there some simple edits I need to make?

Comment: Hmm it seems it means a "staged boost" instead. In the boost source dir, run bootstrap, then "b2 stage". Then ./configure your project, pointing to the boost source dir.

Comment: Gotcha... ok.  That makes some sense, but sounds like I’ll have boost source, boost staged, and boost installed locally, when this is done.  Was going to try the “LPM: local package manager” and hook graph-tool up to it, if I found some way to do that.  You think needs to access boost from env paths like LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @rustyx (reply flag)

Comment: @rustyx this did not work; I run `./b2 stage`, and set `BOOST_ROOT=/path/to/boost` (the folder which contains the stage directory), and no luck